# Mapping Json to cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to display cards in my react component. I have an array of json objects having data to be put in cards. I am using the map function to do this. When I run this code I get just the text in my webpage and no cards. 
Here is my code.

```
const data =
    [
    {
        id: 1,
        Episode_Name : "Game Of Throne S01 E01" ,
        description: "THis is description"
        content: "Hi I am test content"
    },
{
    id: 1,
        Episode_Name : "Game Of Throne S01 E01" ,
        description: "THis is description"
        content: "Hi I am test content"
},
{
   id: 1,
        Episode_Name : "Game Of Throne S01 E01" ,
        description: "THis is description"
        content: "Hi I am test content"
}
];


export default class ExpandableCard extends Component {
    render(){
        var populate = data.map(function (value) {
            return(
                <MuiThemeProvider>
                <card>
                    <CardHeader
                        title={value.Episode_Name}
                        subtitle={value.description}
                        actAsExpander={true}
                        showExpandableButton={true}
                    />
                    <CardText expandable={true}>
                        {value.content}
                    </CardText>
                </card>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            )
        });
        return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
        <div>
            {populate}
        </div>
            <FloatingActionButton className="floatingButton" backgroundColor='#293C8E'>
                <ContentAdd />
            </FloatingActionButton>
        </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The "card" is react component?

Comment: It is import from material ui module.

Comment: Try to change "<card>" to "<Card>"

Comment: Got it. It was a typo. "card" in the place of "Card". Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: First of all, your JSON is broken, missing commas after description. Second, please add your Card component definition. My guess is that is has problems with render()

Comment: @user3761761 please raise my prev comment rate, if it's useful =)